# Java - Cross platform desktop(?) saving

Tags: java, directory, save

Currently I have this:

```
            if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                    if(Library.ManualList.size() > 0){
                        boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                        if(saveYesNo==true){
                            try {
                                File file = new File("Library.txt");
                                System.getProperty("user.home");

                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                                for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                                    pw.println("\n-------------------- Index Number: " + i + " --------------------");
                                    pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                                    pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
                                }
                                pw.close();
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                            }

                        }
                            else if(saveYesNo==false){
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library not saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                        }
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }else if(Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){ 
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It saves a text file in the workspace directory for Eclipse, where the class files are located. However when I export this project to a ".jar" file, I want the text file to be saved in the same dir as the jar file or on the desktop. I have read about "User.home" however as I am new to programming I havent been able to get it to work. Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

---

### edit

updated code:

```
            if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                    if(Library.ManualList.size() > 0){
                        boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                        if(saveYesNo==true){
                            try {
                                String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Library.txt";
                                File file = new File(path);
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                                for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                                    pw.println("\n-------------------- Index Number: " + i + " --------------------");
                                    pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                                    pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
                                }
                                pw.close();
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                            }

                        }
                            else if(saveYesNo==false){
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library not saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                        }
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }else if(Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){ 
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: So this would be cross platform as in you can use it the same way in Linux, Windows, and Mac OS correct?

Comment: @jgr208 correct yes :D

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` would be a start to get the current directory the program is running in, then put that output into a variable and append that variable to the name of the file you want to create. So if you are in dir `foo` `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` would be `foo` and you want to create file **bar** so then append the variable you assigned to `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to get `foo/bar`

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "foo.txt";
File customfile = new File(path);
```

The

`String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "foo.txt";`

gets the current directory the user is in with

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`

then gets the file separator with

`File.separator`

and finally names the text file to be made with

`foo.txt`.

After that,

`File customfile = new File(path);`

makes the new file with the `path` variable which you just created that holds where to put the file.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have attempted to implement your code but I havent noticed any change :( Can you explain where I should implement your code within my existing code?

Comment: sure, I have updated my code with your suggestion at the bottom of my question

Comment: where is the file getting saved now?

Comment: when in eclipse it gets saved to the workspace folder and when exported as a jar it is exported to the home folder, I tried your suggestion but did not export as jar as it was still being saved in the workspace folder

Comment: try mine with the jar

Comment: and that is because of how eclipse works, when you execute the files it does some weird stuff